# how to apply actions to only one instance of a class

Tags: jquery, targeting

I have a form that needs to dynamically generate fields and those fields have various jquery functions called on them.  Basically I am using slideUp and slideDown to show different options based on what the user selects. Consider the following code

```
    <div class="test">
    <div class="red" style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:red; margin-bottom:10px;"></div>
    <div class="green" style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:green;margin-bottom:10px;"></div>
</div>

<div class="test">
    <div class="red" style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:red;margin-bottom:10px;"></div>
    <div class="green" style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:green;margin-bottom:10px;"></div>
</div>
```

And the jquery

```
$('.green').hide();

        $('.red').click(function(){
            $('.green').show();
            });
```

Basically I want only the green box that is after the red one to show.  While this example is simple and I could just duplicate my code and give the second item a different id, my real form is way more complex so what I would like to do is find a way to target items by classname within each "test" div.

Comment: DOM traversal: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both answers are good, i'm just adding another option :

```
$('.red').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings('.green').show();
});
```

Jquery doc : http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Comment: I've selected this answer because I find it to be the easiest to work with, but have tried the others and found them all to be excellent as well. Thank YOu

Answer (score 3):

> what I would like to do is find a way to target items by classname within each "test" div.

Simple enough:

```
$('.red').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.test').find('.green').show();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use next() method:

```
$('.red').click(function () {
    $(this).next('.green').show();
});
```

Comment: If I target something that came before red in the dom order will this still work?

Comment: So, use closest() and find() but this is no more related to your opening question

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$('.green').show();
```

to

```
$(this).parent('.test').children('.green').show();
```